# Can I (holding a private pilots license) fly other employees of my company?

Tags: far-61

I am an HR manager and my job in no way counts on me for flying. I have my private pilots license and a second class medical. If I on occasion fly a company owned aircraft with other employees on it to a fire is that considered “Incidental” under FAR 61.113 (B)(1)?  I would get no bonuses for this and it would fall during normal business hours .

Comment: I'm curious about the *"to a fire"* part of your question. Would this be part of an emergency response? What hazards would involved in the flight? Is there sufficient time for flight planning, particularly for contingencies? I don't know the answer to your question for certain, but it seems very much like this would not be permitted under the "private" license conditions.

Answer (score 7):

You can fly yourself to any business-related function you want and that would be considered "incidental".  As soon as you take paperwork, other employees, other business items, etc. it becomes a question of whether or not you are acting as an air carrier or commercial operator.

[61.113](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-D/part-61/subpart-E/section-61.113) specifically forbids the carriage of passengers or property on these incidental business trips.

I understand there is a clause here about compensation or hire.

The FAA interprets that clause very broadly.  See [Sommer Interpretation (2010)](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/agc/practice_areas/regulations/interpretations/Data/interps/2010/Sommer_2010_Legal_Interpretation.pdf)

I would say not having to do your work while piloting a plane could be considered a form of compensation.  I would not take such a chance in your position.

Comment: The Sommer interpretation doesn't cover this.

Comment: I’m not sure about the “not doing your job” here counts as compensation.  The common test for “incidental” flight is whether you’d also get paid if you drove instead.

Answer (score 4):

Your must ask FAA, they are more than happy to advice you on this matter. I (as well as anybody else here on ASE) have no power to rule on this particular case.

This is not as straightforward as it seems at first glance. The flight would be incidental to your business/work for sure. You would get paid for travelling* regardless of the transport method, so would the passengers. I'm assuming your pay does not change as a result of flying yourself, or taking colleagues as passenger, or transporting business related items.

> (b) A private pilot may, for compensation or hire, act as pilot in command of an aircraft in connection with any business or employment if:
>
> (1) The flight is only incidental to that business or employment; and
>
> (2) The aircraft does not carry passengers or property **for compensation or hire**.

(emphasis mine)

So as long as the flight would yield no financial benefit to you it would *seem* allright. However, also the situation of your employer should be evaluated, as it would benefit from not having to pay for the transport of your colleagues. Not a simple equation at all...

So it's well worth asking the FAA, unless someone comes up with a case that is an exact match to yours.

**depending on your company policy of course*

Comment: Note that the FAA interprets "compensation" extremely broadly. For example, in the decision linked in [wbeard52's answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/94224/3721), a dinner invitation is considered "compensation". And if I remember correctly, it was mentioned in some discussions here on the site that even the fact that the PIC can log hours can be considered compensation if they had otherwise not flown if there hadn't been passengers.

Comment: @JörgWMittag yep, hence the strong recommemdation to ask FAA, not the internet.

Comment: And even if you somehow got a favorable interpretation from the FSDO or a case precedent, they could still nail you later in court if they can find _any_ little detail that deviates from the scenario considered in the FSDO letter / other case. My own advice would be _don't do it_ and don't waste time asking the FAA - no matter their answer you are putting yourself in an uncomfortable legal position in the event of an incident.

Answer (score 1):

No, according to the [Mangiamele Letter](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/agc/practice_areas/regulations/interpretations/data/interps/2009/Mangiamele_2009_Legal_Interpretation.pdf), which is an FAA interpretation of rules, you cannot ask for reimbursement for a business flight if you take passengers:

> In regard to whether you may seek reimbursement from your employer for
> transporting your colleagues, since you are transporting people to the
> meeting, the allowance for the flight to be conducted for compensation
> or hire (i.e., reimbursement) under 61. l 13(b) does not apply. The
> exception in paragraph (b) allows you to use your private pilot
> certificate only for compensation or hire if the operation is
> incidental to your employment and you are not transporting other
> passengers or property. Thus, because you are transporting people to
> the meeting, you may not seek reimbursement from your employer for
> this flight under 14 C.F.R. § 61.113(b).

So in the FAA jurisdiction you would only be able to share costs if you take your colleagues, but if you fly yourself you could be reimbursed.

This isn't universal across the world, in the UK you can take colleagues. So it partly depends on where you are.

Answer (score -2):

" it would fall during normal business hours "

Which means you effectively would get paid for flying them, which is a big nono for a PPL holder. You'd need at least a CPL.
Were you to fly them outside of your normal working hours and not be paid overtime for it, it MIGHT be ok though the cost of the aircraft, parking, and fuel might still be considered payment (I am not sure about that, though some bureaucrat is likely to try that).

Comment: I am not sure this hold. One could argue that the employee is being paid to compensate for the time they are spending traveling to the business meeting. You are being paid this amount regardless whether you are flying yourself, driving yourself, being flown by someone else or being driven by some else. From this it is clear that you are not being paid for the flying, but just for getting your *ss from A to B.

Comment: GdD’s answer contains a ruling from the FAA that specifically allows it in some circumstances (but not others), so this general answer is incorrect or at least incomplete.